# how to get li first href in a UL using javascript

Tags: javascript

everyone i want to get all first href elements in li and i want it in javascript only

```
 <div id="cataloge">
 <ul id="catalog-items" class="product-items"> 
  <li id="OS389HL91QJCLMX" class="product-item >
  <a id="1:OS389HL91QJCLMX"  href="/piezas-y-Sala-4-piezas%29.-116508.html">link1
  <ul><li>some data</li><li>some data</li><li>some data</li></ul>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li id="OS389HL91QJCLMX" class="product-item >
  <a id="1:OS389HL91QJCLMX"  href="/piezas-y-Sala-4-piezas%29.-116508.html">link1
  <ul><li>some data</li><li>some data</li><li>some data</li></ul>
  </a>
  </li>
  <li id="OS389HL91QJCLMX" class="product-item >
  <a id="1:OS389HL91QJCLMX"  href="/piezas-y-Sala-4-piezas%29.-116508.html">link1
  <ul><li>some data</li><li>some data</li><li>some data</li></ul>
  </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div>
```

i want get href links in the li classname **"product-item"** under UL with id catalog-    items

i written this below code,but it is giving empty when print the chethan1;

```
  var lists = document.getElementById("catalog-items");
  var items = lists.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var chethan1="";
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  { 
   if(typeof items[i]!="undefined" && items[i]!="" && items[i].className=="product-item")
   {
    chethan1.push(items[i]);
   }
  }

  console.log(chethan1);
  [empty]
```

plz someone help me to sort out..thanks in advance..

Comment: Please provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rnsQv/

Comment: `id`s should be unique, you have multiple elements with a same `id`.

Comment: ya..ids are diiferent and dynamic,for to show a example i just copied and paste it...i dnt want refer with ids.all i want is with classname "product-item";

Comment: No close quote after class: class="product-item >.  Close it, then follow below with new Array() as your push does not work.

Comment: here i forgotton to close..but its there in source code.@BumptiousQBangwhistle

Comment: if you close it in your fiddle, then follow new Array() below, your fiddle works.

Comment: @BumptiousQBangwhistle i tried with new Array() also,but it is giving empty.

Answer (score 0):

Among other markup concerns, `.push()` is to be used on arrays, not strings.

Use `var chethan1 = [];` instead of `var chethan1="";`.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9YJz/1)

Comment: or better, `var chetan1 = []`

Comment: I disagree. Markup fixed and replace the string with an empty array: http://jsfiddle.net/t9YJz/1/

Comment: ya..i also agree.i wil check in my source code and check..thanks alot. @DerekSchlesselman

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/M5xYb/

```
  var chethan1= new Array();
```

Closes string, uses new array from above.  Results are not empty.

Comment: yes it is working...thanks alot..thank u very much. i wil check in my source code.thanks once again

Comment: np.  There were two unclosed strings in your fiddle.  Give credit to Derek, he caught the push().